# AWS EKS - On prem Worker node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am new to AWS EKS - I have an application for which I need one worker node (a pod) of the Kubernetes to run on my on-premise infrastructure. Is that possible and if yes then how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can run EKS and on-prem kubernetes clusters at the same time, but managing them via a single [federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) control plane. But I've never tried to use it with EKS, although EKS is mostly vanilla kubernetes, so it should work.